# The Heinz Dilemma in Halacha

Tags: pikuachnefesh-danger-life, mussar-ethics, gezel-stealing

A famous [Kohlberg dilemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinz_dilemma) goes something like this:

Heinz’s wife is dying and there’s a drug that may be able to save her. Jack cannot afford the drug.

Can Heinz steal the drug to treat his wife?
What’s the Halacha in this case?

Comment: Closely related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92443/is-stealing-food-ok

Comment: @DoubleAA Claiming this is a duplicate is making a Halachik presumption that may or may not be accurate.

Comment: @LN6595 what assumption is that? I guess technically I should have closed in the opposite direction, since food is a subset of drug. In any event, if you feel this isn't a duplicate please edit to clarify how it is different