# Is it a Sin to take from a Rasha?

Tags: halacha

Is it a sin if a righteous man steals from a Rasha? Say the Jews stole from the Nazis during WW2 to feed themselves or help themselves.

Comment: For stealing to survive, see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92443/is-stealing-food-ok

Answer (score 1):

It is forbidden to steal, from Jew or Gentile, even from an individual who has caused you pain. [Shulchan Aruch Harav, Laws of Theft 1]

Comment: True, but this doesn't address the example in the question.

Comment: @msh210 there are two questions in the question. "Stealing to survive" (yes) and broadly "okay to steal from anybody I deem evil" (no, and scoped broadly enough to include anyone I don't like).